# ImportError: cannot import name NavigationToolbar2QTAgg

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4, pyqtgraph

I have a PyQt4 app project I'd like to turn into an .exe on Windows. I `cd` to the main script and run `pyinstaller SPCanalyse.py`. When I try to run the .exe I get:

```
C:\Users\user\Documents\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse>C:\Users\user\Documents
\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\dist\SPCanalyse\SPCanalyse.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
SPCanalyse returned -1
```

Reading [this](https://github.com/semiautomaticgit/SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin/issues/2) I did try to add from `matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT` to the top of `SPCanalyse.py` but to no avail. Though I'm surprised I still have the error since it looks like they fixed it.

I have matplotlib version 1.5.1 and I did find that [NavigationToolbar2QTAgg was removed](http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/api_changes.html?highlight=navigationtoolbar2qtagg#remove-navigationtoolbar2qtagg) in this version which I'm certain has to do with why I get the error. So if it was removed, why does my code try to import it? How do I prevent this attempted import?

Note that I am having zero problems running my app on Ubuntu.

Cmd output when running pyinstaller:

```
D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse>pyinstaller SPCanalyse.py
49 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
49 INFO: Python: 2.7.11
49 INFO: Platform: Windows-7-6.1.7601-SP1
49 INFO: wrote D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\SPCanalyse.spec
49 INFO: UPX is not available.
49 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['D:\\Home\\Downloads\\BMDanalyse',
 'D:\\Home\\Downloads\\BMDanalyse\\BMDanalyse']
59 INFO: checking Analysis
89 INFO: Building because c:\python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\__init__.py
 changed
89 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
99 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
119 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
129 INFO: Adding Microsoft.VC90.CRT to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\python27\python.exe
200 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
200 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_f47e1bd6f6571810.manifest
200 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_f47c47b2f658b4a8.manifest
200 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
269 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.307
29.4940_none ...
279 INFO: Found manifest C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8
b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742.manifest
279 INFO: Searching for file msvcr90.dll
279 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9
.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\msvcr90.dll
279 INFO: Searching for file msvcp90.dll
279 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9
.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\msvcp90.dll
279 INFO: Searching for file msvcm90.dll
279 INFO: Found file C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9
.0.30729.4940_none_50916076bcb9a742\msvcm90.dll
349 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.1_none_8550c6b5d18a9128.manifest
349 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_f47e1bd6f6571810.manifest
349 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_f47c47b2f658b4a8.manifest
349 INFO: Found C:\Windows\WinSxS\Manifests\x86_policy.9.0.microsoft.vc90.crt_1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4940_none_f47ed0f6f6564d90.manifest
349 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0,
30729, 4940)
389 INFO: Analyzing D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\SPCanalyse.py
1101 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
2987 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   _xmlplus
3118 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
3118 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages\\PyIn
staller\\fake-modules'
3138 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
4625 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
7777 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt4.uic.port_v3
7787 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   PyQt4.uic.port_v2
8948 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
8958 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PySide.QtGui.py
9345 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
9345 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sysconfig.py
9345 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
9345 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
9355 INFO: Excluding import 'FixTk'
9355 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
9355 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
9355 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.qRgba
9355 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QPixmap
9355 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5
9355 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QImage
9355 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtGui
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtGui.QPixmap
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtCore
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtCore.QBuffer
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtGui.QImage
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtCore.QIODevice
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QtGui.qRgba
9365 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QImage
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QPixmap
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QIODevice
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QBuffer
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.qRgba
9365 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui
9365 INFO: Processing hook   hook-httplib.py
9365 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pydoc.py
9365 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
9365 WARNING:   From pydoc removing import Tkinter
9375 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtTest.py
9375 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.py
9375 INFO: Processing hook   hook-_tkinter.py
9486 INFO: checking Tree
9527 INFO: checking Tree
9537 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.backends.py
9978 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
10319 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
10523 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named gtk
10843 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": ignored
    cannot import name _macosx
11184 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
11527 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
11858 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
12187 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
12497 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
12710 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
13029 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
13615 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": added
13845 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    No module named IPython.display
14167 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
14496 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": added
14707 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "emf": ignored
    No module named backend_emf
14917 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named gobject
15238 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
15621 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
15965 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
16290 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
16621 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
16744 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
16934 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.py
17151 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.uic.py
17161 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.dom.domreg.py
17161 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtGui.py
17421 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pkg_resources.py
17572 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PySide.QtCore.py
17644 INFO: Processing hook   hook-certifi.py
17644 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pytz.py
17714 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pywintypes.py
17881 INFO: Processing hook   hook-setuptools.py
17881 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py
17881 INFO: Excluding import 'FixTk'
17881 INFO: Excluding import 'Tkinter'
17881 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
18141 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtSvg.py
18141 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py
18141 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PySide.py
18141 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtCore.py
18201 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtOpenGL.py
18201 INFO: Processing hook   hook-win32com.py
18261 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pythoncom.py
18471 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
18491 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
18501 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
18501 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'
18511 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'
18511 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
18511 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
18511 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
18511 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
18532 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
18922 INFO: Searching for assembly x86_Microsoft.VC90.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.2
1022.8_none ...
18922 INFO: Found manifest c:\python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\Microsoft.VC9
0.MFC.manifest
18922 INFO: Searching for file mfc90.dll
18922 INFO: Found file c:\python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90.dll
18922 INFO: Searching for file mfc90u.dll
18922 INFO: Found file c:\python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfc90u.dll
18922 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90.dll
18922 INFO: Found file c:\python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90.dll
18922 INFO: Searching for file mfcm90u.dll
18922 INFO: Found file c:\python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin\mfcm90u.dll
18993 INFO: Adding redirect Microsoft.VC90.MFC version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0
, 21022, 8)
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PyQt4.QtCore
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PyQt4.QtTest
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PyQt4.QtGui
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PyQt4.QtOpenGL
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PyQt4.QtSvg
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtCore
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.shiboken
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtTest
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtOpenGL
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtSvg
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtNetwork
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PySide.QtGui
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PIL._webp
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PIL._imagingtk
19713 WARNING: Attempted to add Python module twice with different upper/lowerca
ses: PIL._imaging
19713 INFO: Looking for eggs
19713 INFO: Using Python library C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll
19713 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.CRT', language=None, arch=u'x86', oldVers
ion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 30729, 4940), publicKeyToken=u'1fc8b3b9a
1e18e3b'), BindingRedirect(name=u'Microsoft.VC90.MFC', language=None, arch=u'x86
', oldVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), newVersion=(9, 0, 21022, 8), publicKeyToken=u'1f
c8b3b9a1e18e3b')]
19733 INFO: Warnings written to D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\build\SP
Canalyse\warnSPCanalyse.txt
20092 INFO: checking PYZ
20092 INFO: Building because toc changed
20102 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\b
uild\SPCanalyse\out00-PYZ.pyz
21024 INFO: checking PKG
21024 INFO: Building because toc changed
21024 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) out00-PKG.pkg
21056 INFO: Bootloader c:\python27\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Wind
ows-32bit\run.exe
21056 INFO: checking EXE
21057 INFO: Building because out00-EXE.toc is bad
21059 INFO: Building EXE from out00-EXE.toc
21059 INFO: Appending archive to EXE D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\bui
ld\SPCanalyse\SPCanalyse.exe
21065 INFO: checking COLLECT
WARNING: The output directory "D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\dist\SPCa
nalyse" and ALL ITS CONTENTS will be REMOVED! Continue? (y/n)y
24730 INFO: Removing dir D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse\dist\SPCanalyse

25009 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc
25029 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25159 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25159 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qtcore.pyd
25159 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25180 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25180 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.shiboken.pyd
25180 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25190 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25190 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qttest.pyd
25200 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25210 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25210 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qtopengl.pyd
25210 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25220 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25230 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qtsvg.pyd
25230 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25240 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25240 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qtnetwork.pyd
25240 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25580 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25580 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside.qtgui.pyd
25580 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25661 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25661 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\_elementtree.pyd
25661 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25740 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25740 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\pyside-python2.7.dll
25740 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25750 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25750 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\shiboken-python2.7.dll
25760 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033
25780 INFO: Redirecting Microsoft.VC90.CRT version (9, 0, 21022, 8) -> (9, 0, 30
729, 4940)
25780 INFO: Updating manifest in C:\Users\Cornelis\AppData\Roaming\pyinstaller\b
incache00_py27_32bit\qtnetwork4.dll
25780 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 2 language 1033

D:\Home\Downloads\BMDanalyse\BMDanalyse>
```

Comment: I've lost the name of the script now but changing NavigationToolbar2QTAgg to NavigationToolbar2QT in one of the pyqtgraph scripts resolved the issue. Therefore I surmise pyqtgraph has not been updated yet to reflect the removal of the API

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I've done this a million times now. When you see this:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/BMDanalyse/BMDanalyse/SPCanalyse.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/BMDanalyse/BMDanalyse/SPCanalyse.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pyqtgraph.widgets.MatplotlibWidget import MatplotlibWidget
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\MatplotlibWidget.py", line 8, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
ImportError: cannot import name NavigationToolbar2QTAgg
```

Go to the offending line in `MatplotlibWidget.py` and change

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QTAgg as NavigationToolbar
```

to this:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

Yes, you're changing backend code permanently for this fix. I haven't had any problems after making this change. `NavigationToolbar2QTAgg` was removed in `matplotlib 1.5.0`

Comment: no it is not removed in 1.5.1. I am using it now. getting same error.

Comment: The API Changes seems to clearly list it as removed in 1.5.0 onwards: http://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/api_changes.html?highlight=navigationtoolbar2qtagg#remove-navigationtoolbar2qtagg
"Remove NavigationToolbar2QTAgg - Added no functionality over the base NavigationToolbar2Qt" <- that's from their listed changes

Comment: @Frikster Do you know how to fix this problem if I'm using Tkinter , not PyQT?

Comment: @Aleksandar It is difficult without seeing your error message exactly. In my case there was an import error caused by pyqtgraph which you can see in the question: File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyqtgraph\widgets\MatplotlibWidget.py". I have checked on github and since posting this they have fixed this issue so you shouldn't have it anymore if you're using pytgraph. Either way, the error message is what led me to where I needed to go exactly. In your case it would likely be different and it might not even have much to do with Tkinter.

Comment: Im using Tkinter for GUI and my error is: from `matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
ImportError: cannot import name 'NavigationToolbar2TkAgg'`
I looked all over the web but It always directs me to this question

Comment: `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` is deprecated just like `NavigationToolbar2QTAgg`. 

If you look here it looks like you should be using `NavigationToolbar2Tk` not `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`:

https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.0.0.html?highlight=navigationtoolbar2tkagg

Open the file `matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py` and change `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg` to `NavigationToolbar2Tk`. Make that one change. Save it. See what it changes.

Comment: To anyone else having similar problems what you can do is go to this site - https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/api_changes.html?highlight=navigationtoolbar2qtagg#remove-navigationtoolbar2qtagg - and type in the package that seems to have a problem importing (e.g. `NavigationToolbar2TkAgg`) in the quick search in the right sidebar. Go through each search results and on each page ctrl F search for the package and you'll likely find information on whether it has been deprecated and what to replace it with.